# Alternative question titles to reduce duplicates

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-suggestions

Some questions are hard to search for because they are phrased in different ways. Is there a way to create an "alternate question title" to reduce the chance that someone will create a duplicate? The other option is to create a duplicate question then close it and link to the original question, but I don't think people will like this option.

Comment: Probably a dupe...

Comment: I tried searching, but couldn't find it

Comment: Must be because it was using alternative words and synonyms.

Comment: Anyone have a dupe link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The other option is to create a duplicate question then close it and link to the original question, but I don't think people will like this option.

I don't like this option. I think the duplicate should automatically redirect to the original.

Unfortunately, this is the option [that has been implemented](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/). Just gotta deal with it, i guess...

Comment: I'm confused now: so it is legitimate to write a new question for an existing question with improvable wording, and close it as duplicate?

Comment: @Alberto: probably best to just let it happen naturally.

Comment: My point is that in a few occasions, trying to find a solution to a problem took me quite a long time. It turned out that there already were a corresponding question with a good answer in SO, but due to a different OP's approach to the problem, or due to poor wording, I couldn't find the answers easily. I know I'll face some of these problems again, and would like to help myself by rewriting the question. I have considered adding a new wording as a comment to the OP's question, but I'm not sure if this will help the search (are comments indexed?), nor if it won't be considered to disruptive...

Comment: I agree with Alberto, probably best to act proactively.

Answer (score 2):

I am all for this! Currently, there are (at least) two identical questions regarding whether they should use 64bit Windows 7 or not. The 'duplicate' question was not closed because the title was worded differently. Although I do believe it is important to have multiple titles (just like Wikipedia does) for the same question, I do not believe there should be two completely disjointed discussions on the same topic.

Perhaps a link to 'additional discussions' would be handy, just like reddit does for duplicate submissions

Comment: I'd suggest effective a tag-like solution. Similar to how it looks now except it shouldn't appear as a duplicate just simply the very same body of question under the very same hyperlink with a sort of mark at the end of the question to indicate it is an alternative question of the original one, and allow for user prompt to see the original or other alternative titles. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Most people create poor question titles, so how will they do any better making a second one?

Comment: Not sure about *most*, but it is certainly common enough (most of my non-retag edits seem to have been about rewording titles).

Comment: Those people are unlikely to create an "alternate question title".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt and ranking-based tool sets may be put in place for non-mods to respond to such scenarios, and there may be a reputation-level requirement put in place for on to be able to directly suggest one.

Comment: @Lance Roberts "Most people want to stick their head in the sand and ignore problems, in an effort to avoid [;] I refuse to be that passive person. Problems are there to be fixed, which means that first they have to identified[; d]enial is not just a river in Egypt." I think you did identify a problem here! Let's make it a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A few practical considerations for implementation on the user end:

Search engines should be able to see the questions with the answers effectively as duplicates. That way those looking for the answer would legitimately see the specific question they are looking for, and when they clicked, the alternative title should be visible.

For cases when a title question linked to a specific question happens to not create a substantially identical scope of inquiry as the original, vote to close, delete, flag and moderator tools could be put in place to clear up.

From SE users perspective, they shouldn't appear as dupes, but a single question, and alternative questions should only appear on, for e.g., a click of a button or similar user prompt.

Additional features may involve...

When a question is being composed by a user, and the data model of the site offers a question that was previously asked, and the user, say, upvotes it or its answers, and eventually does not file or continue to compose a new question, if a question title was typed out, it should go to certain privilege holding user for approval to be implemented as an alternative question for indexing the knowledge base.

If a question is submitted and a user votes to close on the basis of it being a "duplicate", if OP finds that the other question inquires the same scope, the site should allow them to confirm, and automatically add their question as an alternative title question, and depending on reputation and privileges, either prompt higher privilege users or mods to double check or simply accept the alt-title question.

This would also help us change mentalities and start to think of users trying to ask the "same" question, that is, make the same inquiry, by a *different* question, and make away with a whole aspect of the site thought of as disruptive and undesirable (people asking "duplicates") and start creating a rewarding mentality about it as we realize it creates a knowledge base of indexes.